# MySQL syntax for summing several count data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called `things_they_own` with two columns: `person` and `thing` and my primary key is the combination of the two.  Thus, there are several rows where the first column is a certain `person` with the `thing` column being different for each, and several rows where the second column is a certain `thing` and the first column different for each (i.e., each person can own several things and each thing can be owned by several people).

**What I want to do:** find how many `thing`s an inputted `person` shares with every other `person`, using **just one** MySQL query.

**My current solution:** I'm coding in PHP.  I've created an array called `$things_person_owns` which has all the `thing`s that an inputted person owns, and an array called '$things_in_common_count' which has all the `person`s as keys and all the values are initially set as 0.  Then, I do this:

```
foreach ($things_person_owns as $a_thing) {
    $query = "select person from things_they_own where thing = $a_thing";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while ($theresult = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $person = $theresult[0];
        $things_in_common_count[$person] += 1;
    }
}
```

**The problem:** PHP sends one MySQL query for every `thing` that the inputted person owns, and each query takes like 0.1s to execute, so it is very slow.

For that reason, I want to find a MySQL-alone solution for my problem, so I could execute only 1 query.

Thank you so much in advance and sorry for any bad wording!

Comment: `find how many things an inputted person shares with every other person` - from this statement, that means if every person doesn't own the same thing, it shouldn't be counted? It would help to clarify your question if you include sample data and desired output.

Comment: @fubar That's correct and you have a good point re data.  If I don't get a good answer, I'll add sample data.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the database properly indexed? What is the data's incoming source for the `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I've modified my answer.

First, here's a list of every person in the table and a count of the things they share in common with a given person (excluding the person being considered).

```
SELECT tto.person, COUNT(*) AS same_things
FROM things_they_own tto
INNER JOIN things_they_own tto2 ON tto.person <> tto2.person AND tto.thing = tto2.thing
WHERE tto2.person = 'Person A'
GROUP BY tto.person;
```

[Working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WfWjJQSeEZ6XSY94FFtP7/2).

As a bonus, here's a list of every person and thing, together with a comma separated list of each other person that owns the same thing.

```
SELECT tto.person, tto.thing, GROUP_CONCAT(tto2.person ORDER BY tto2.person SEPARATOR ', ') AS also_owned_by
FROM things_they_own tto
INNER JOIN things_they_own tto2 ON tto.person <> tto2.person AND tto.thing = tto2.thing
GROUP BY tto.person, tto.thing
ORDER BY tto.person, tto.thing
```

If you want to limit the result to a single person, just add a `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE tto.person = 'Person A'
```

[Working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WfWjJQSeEZ6XSY94FFtP7/1).

Comment: My fault for not being more clear.  Sorry.  What I really wanted to do was to see, given a `person`, a list of every other `person` in the table along with how many `thing`s each of those `person`s shares with the given `person`